# Error playing GZIPped video directly into an MediaPlayerElement (UWP)

Tags: uwp, gzip, dotnet-httpclient

I have a MP4 video store in a Blob on Azure and compressed using GZIP format.

If the video is not compressed, I can read it directly using this code in the UWP app:

```
<MediaPlayerElement x:Name="_mediaPlayerElement" />
```

and

```
this._mediaPlayerElement.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(uri);
this._mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Play();
```

Now if the video is compressed, I have the following error "Error: Unsupported video type or invalid file path".

I then try to decompress it using `HttpClient` and passing the stream to the `mediaPlayerElement`. I have tested this implementation of `MediaPlayerElementWithHttpClient` ([here](https://github.com/kiewic/MediaPlayerElementWithHttpClient)) or my custom class. But it's not working either. (The original video works but not the GZIP).

I have, of course, activated the `AutomationDecompression` of the `HttpClient`.

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{    
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
};

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Is it possible to stream a GZIP video in UWP?

Using this website http://v4e.thewikies.com/, an HTML video code generator, I can play the GZIP video directly from the browser (Firefox, Chrome is not working). I assume it's doable but how in UWP?

(Not related directly but if I display an image compressed with GZIP in my UWP app it's working.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may download the `.mp4.gz` file to the local folder, by testing on my side, it could be download to a `.mp4` file correctly. Then load the `MediaSource` from file instead. For example:

```
using Windows.Web.Http;

HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
IBuffer buffers = await httpclient.GetBufferAsync(uri); 
StorageFolder localfolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile tempfile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("temp.mp4", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(tempfile, buffers);
this._mediaPlayerElement.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/temp.mp4"));
this._mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Play();
```

Comment: This way is easy but not what I'm trying to do. I don't want to download the whole file to a cache (if the file is big > 1go). I'd like to "stream" the content to the MediaPlayerElement. I can stream a video (from azure) to the MediaPlayerElement if this video is not GZIP compressed.